# Prototype Bean injected in a singleton bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have injected a prototyte bean 'B' in a singleton bean 'A' as given below..

```
<bean id="a" class="com.user.processor.A" >
<property name="objectb" ref="b"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="com.user.processor.B" scope="prototype">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

---

```
public class A { 

    private B objectb; 

    public String process() { 

        objectb.setX("asdf"); 
        System.out.println("value of x : " objectb.getX() ); 

    } 

    public void setobjectb(B objectb){ 
        this.objectb = objectb; 
    } 

}
```

---

The prototype bean 'B' contains variables and getters & setters for those variables.

In one of the methods of A I'm accessing setter method of B to set a variable, after setting if I print that variable using getter method NULL is returned.

Each time while accessing a method in B its returning a new object of B.

I want new B object to be returned only when bean A is invoked.. not for the invocation of each method in B... How can i do this...

Comment: can u show in code how you are accessing B inside A's method?

Comment: @Karibasappa..

public class A {

private B objectb;

public String process() {
   
   objectB.setX("asdf");
   System.out.println("value of x : " objectB.getX() );
}


public void setobjectB(B objectb){
   this.objectb = objectb;
}


}

Comment: where and how are you accessing setter method of B using A's bean ?

Answer (score 0):

you are using defferent property name in the bean definition of A.

like below

```
<bean id="a" class="com.user.processor.A" >
<property name="responseObject" ref="b"/>
</bean>
```

here property name is `responseObject` but in the Class A definition the property name
for B is `objectb` which is not having any reference in A's bean definition in xml.

so change the name either in xml or class A and make them same.

let me know if for any issues.

Comment: Sorry.. its Typo.. now i changed in the question.. actually in code am having same property name only..

Comment: Why are you using <aop:scoped-proxy/> ?

Comment: <aop:scoped-proxy/> used here to inject a prototype bean into a singleton bean or lookup method injection has to be used.   If not given then it will be like singleton only..